Sum of Bessel functions $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\jmath^{n_0+Mn}J_{n_0+Mn}(z)e^{\jmath (n_0+Mn)\theta}$
Hi， I am working on the sum of bessel functions:
$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\jmath^{n_0+Mn}J_{n_0+Mn}(z)e^{\jmath (n_0+Mn)\theta}$, where $M$ is a positive integer, $n_0$ is a integer.
I think it is a general form of Jacobi expansion, we know that
$e^{jz cos\theta}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\jmath^{n}J_n(z)e^{\jmath n\theta}$.
But I have no idea how to calculate it.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection

In the following I will provide a physicist proof where I will make one step without justifying it. I suppose that a complete proof would require considering equalities in the sense of distributions.
Using the Jacobi-Anger expansion that you mentioned, $j^{n}J_{n}(z)$ are Fourier coefficients of $e^{jz\cos{\theta}}$. That is,
\begin{align}
\jmath^{n_0+Mn}J_{n_0+Mn}(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{jz\cos \phi} e^{-j(n_{0}+Mn)\phi}\textit{d}\phi
\end{align}
We may use that formula inside of the sum
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\jmath^{n_0+Mn}J_{n_0+Mn}(z)e^{\jmath (n_0+Mn)\theta}= \frac{1 }{2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{jz\cos \phi} e^{j(n_{0}+Mn) \left( \theta - \phi \right)}\textit{d}\phi
\end{align}
We will exchange sum and integral (this is the part that I should maybe justify using distributions)
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\jmath^{n_0+Mn}J_{n_0+Mn}(z)e^{\jmath (n_0+Mn)\theta}= \frac{1 }{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{jz\cos \phi}e^{jn_{0}(\theta-\phi)}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{jMn(\theta-\phi)}\textit{d}\theta
\end{align}
The sum at the right hand side above is the Fourier series of the Dirac comb so we can replace that sum with the Dirac comb using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel#Relation_to_the_periodic_delta_function (I did not check if that formula is correct you might want to verify that using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\jmath^{n_0+Mn}J_{n_0+Mn}(z)e^{\jmath (n_0+Mn)\theta}=\frac{1}{M}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{jz\cos \phi}e^{jn_{0}(\theta-\phi)}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta( \phi-\theta-\frac{2\pi k}{M})\textit{d}\phi
\end{align}
Using the periodicity of the sum on the right hand side, we may restrict $\theta$ to be between 0 and $2\pi$. Consider then a subdivision, $x_{m}= \frac{2\pi m }{M} $ with $m$ an integer between 0 and $M$. There exists an $m_{0}$ such that $2\pi m_{0}/M\le \theta \leq 2 \pi (m_{0}+1)/M$ with $0\leq m_{0 }\leq M- 1$. As $0\leq \phi\le2\pi$, $\phi=\theta+2\pi k/M $ implies that $- m_{0 }\leq k \leq M-1 - m_{0 }$. If we use the $2\pi$ periodicity of the integrand on the right hand side, we can add $M$ to the integers in the interval $[- m_{0 },-1]$ so that $k$ has integer values in the interval $[0,M-1]$. Therefore, using the definition of the Dirac function, we obtain the final result:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\jmath^{n_0+Mn}J_{n_0+Mn}(z)e^{\jmath (n_0+Mn)\theta}=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}e^{j \left(  z\cos \left(\theta+ \frac{2\pi k}{M}  \right) -\frac{2\pi n_{0}k}{M}\right)} 
\end{align}

I should maybe mention that the "physics proof" above started by looking for a way to find the final answer using the integral representation of the Dirac function as the wikipedia page suggested by metamorphy shows a formula which looks like averaging exponential cancellations and it is a common technique in physics to introduce a Dirac function to express a constraint and then use the exponential integral representation of the Dirac function.

Wow! Your solution is inspiring. Thank you so much!

@madao I think the final result is correct as it seems to be the same as what was provided in the wikipedia link by the other user in the comments below your post but I did not verify that the formula for the Dirac comb has the right factors. You might want to check that the formula works numerically for a few values of M.
